# Angular 4 - How to route between pages with different Layout (header and footer)?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm a beginner with Angular 2+.

My project consists of a landing pages referred towards as Home and About pages which have header and footer related to the landing pages.
There's a login button and after the login button the header and footer change for dashboard (The menu is hidden color change etc).

Currently, I've set routing in my project in app.module.ts as follows:

```
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
```

Now **routing works fine and the header and footer load fine but when I navigate to localhost/dashboard the header and footer of the landing pages appear there as well which is obvious** since I've placed them in my app.component.html file as

```
<header-nav></header-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Question: 
**What I want to achieve is when "/dashboard" is loaded in url the header and footer from app.component.html are not loaded and its own header and footer from a different component.html file are loaded.**

Approach 1: I can add header and footer to each of the html pages of each component and only router-outlet to app.component.html so respective elements will be loaded on each page.

I'm looking for a better approach where /dashboard loads from a different component.html file and I can easily create landing pages app.component.html
as

```
<header-nav></header-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

and dashboard.component.html as

```
<dashboard-header></dashboard-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a LandingComponent and DashboardComponent.
Landing Component then can have it's own child routes that need the landing layout
and same applies for dashboard.

routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LandingComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'features',
        component: FeaturesComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'analytics',
        component: AnalyticsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

landing.component.html

```
<landing-header></landing-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<landing-footer></landing-footer>
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<dashboard-header></dashboard-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<dashboard-footer></dashboard-footer>
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well
Now the issue is when I navigate to a page from homepage for e.g localhost/about from there when I try to click the contact page it does not load and it shows the url as localhost/about/(contact) however if from home page I directly open contact page it opens
 ` path:'', 
        component: FrontendLayoutComponent,
        children: 
        [
            { path:'', component: IndexComponent },
            { path:'about', component: AboutComponent },
            { path:'contact', component: ContactComponent },
        ] `

Comment: ↑ Solved now. Was missing a "/" in routerLink. Previously it was routerLink="contact" changed it to routerLink="/contact" and now everything works fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your `<header-nav></header-nav>` into app.component.html  and put each every component.html where you want it. Same for `<dashboard-header></dashboard-header>`
where you want it put it directly that component.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ngIf to show and hide elements by route. So if you need to show header only on the specific routes this is best case scenario.

Example:

```
*ngIf="router.url === '/some/route'"
```